# vb.net code reads lables wrong

Tags: vb.net, windows, visual-studio-2010

Okay, so I am making a game, like cookie clicker, or in my case - http://www.silvergames.com/poop-clicker (don't ask...), so that when you click on the icon in the center, it changes the total value by adding 1.  On the side, you have a picture which you click to increase the amount it generates automatically every second.
At the moment I have it like this:

The timer tics every second. If the total amount > the cost of upgrade then it shows the picture of the thing you click to upgrade.

When you click that picture - 
The cost is taken away from the total amount. 
It changes the amount of times you have used that upgrade by +1.
The automatic upgrades per second is changed by +1.
The Cost is increased by 10.

What is happening is that I click the icon in the middle say 5 times (very quickly) and it only comes up with a total of 3.  That in itself is a problem, but the even worse problem is that it shows the picture to click, when i told it to only show when the total value was > 10 (the cost of the upgrade).

I am really confused, and any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks
SkySpear

PS. Here's the Code -

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub picPoop_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles picPoop.Click
    lblPoops.Text = lblPoops.Text + 1
End Sub

Private Sub picCursor_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles picCursor.Click
    lblPoops.Text = lblPoops.Text - lblCursorCost.Text
    lblCursorAmmount.Text = lblCursorAmmount.Text + 1
    lblPoopsPerSec.Text = lblPoopsPerSec.Text + 1
    lblCursorCost.Text = lblCursorCost.Text + 10
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    lblCursorAmmount.Text = 0
    lblCursorCost.Text = 10
    lblBabyAmmount.Text = 0
    lblBabyCost.Text = 100
    lblBowlAmmount.Text = 0

    picCursor.Hide()
    tmrSec.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub tmrSec_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tmrSec.Tick
    If lblPoops.Text > lblCursorCost.Text Then picCursor.Show()
End Sub
End Class
```

Again, don't ask where this ridiculous idea came from, I can assure you it wasn't mine.

Comment: if you turn on OPTION STRICT a whole host of type conversions will be highlighted.  NET provides several good conversion methods such as `n = Integer.Parse(textbox.text)` to convert text (strngs) to numeric values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem with this is that in your Timer sub, you are comparing text to text.  In this case, a value of "3" > "21", since text comparisons work on a char by char basis.  When this happens, your pictureBox is being shown.  As others suggested, you can use any of the string to numeric conversion functions in your timer event to make this work better.

A slightly better approach would be to declare some class level numeric variables that hold each individual value and displays them when needed.  As an example

```
numPoops += 1
lblPoops.Text = numPoops
```

This will make sure that all math will work correctly.

Answer (score -1):

You are dealing with the Value of the textboxes, not the Text in it.
You should enclose each textbox with VAL() to get its exact value as a number.

```
Private Sub picPoop_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles picPoop.Click
    lblPoops.Text = VAL(lblPoops.Text) + 1
End Sub

Private Sub picCursor_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles picCursor.Click
    lblPoops.Text = VAL(lblPoops.Text) - VAL(lblCursorCost.Text)
    lblCursorAmmount.Text = VAL(lblCursorAmmount.Text) + 1
    lblPoopsPerSec.Text = VAL(lblPoopsPerSec.Text) + 1
    lblCursorCost.Text = VAL(lblCursorCost.Text) + 10
End Sub

Private Sub tmrSec_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tmrSec.Tick
    If VAL(lblPoops.Text) > VAL(lblCursorCost.Text) Then picCursor.Show()
End Sub
```

Comment: Not your downvoter, but shouldn't you use tryparse() when expecting user input and then notify if the entered string is invalid? I would think using VAL() function could lead to unexpected results.